# How do I redirect to the domain and keep url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I've been trying to do is take any pathname beyond the domain and redirect it to the root of the site, but keeping the url.

I was at a point where I could get `http://example.com/something` to redirect and keep the url, however `http://example.com/something/` (trailingslash) would mess up the css, images, etc. I've since lost that...

Where I'm at now is that anything after `http://example.com/` will give me a 404.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1 [L,R=302]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

To clarify. I will have traffic coming into the site via url structures like:
`http://example.com/something`
However, nothing lives at those directories. I don't want a 404, but instead want to show whatever content is at the root level. I still want the user to see the url they typed though. I will be parsing that url later in javascript.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've updated the post. Hope that helps. Thanks for looking.

Comment: what do you mean by top-level? give an example

Comment: I meant root. So, what would be displayed to the user would be the root level of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L]
```

You should also add `<base href="/" />` just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML, so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out. Will this also keep the url in the address bar as the user entered it?

Comment: Yes it will keep same URL in address bar.

Comment: Thanks :) I have to update my stylesheet urls so that they have a leading slash, but otherwise it works. Thank you much.